# How to display unique items in an SQLite database to a Picker in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an assignment and am stock at populating items from a column in the SQLite database to a picker here is my code

from the database model

```
public IEnumerable<SingleSignerTable> GetItemList()
{
    return _database.Query<SingleSignerTable>("SELECT * FROM [SingleSignerTable]");
}
```

from the front end

```
lCategory = new Label
            {
                Text = "Category",
                FontAttributes = Font.SystemFontOfSize(5, FontAttributes.Bold).FontAttributes,
            };
lField = new Picker { Title = "Category", VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start };

lField.SelectedIndexChanged += lSport_SelectedIndexChanged;

FieldOption = new List<string> { "Others", GetItemList()};
foreach (string option in FieldOption)
{
    lField.Items.Add(option);
};

private string GetItemList()
{
    foreach (string option in FieldOption)
    {
        lField.Items.Add(option);
    };
}
```

so that I can get these for example

> Others
>       Baseball
>       Soccer
>       Volleyball
>       Scrabble
>       WWE

in the picker end

but the code doesn't seem to work

Comment: Why isn't it working? Do you get an error? Does the picker stay empty?

Comment: yes at private string GetItemList()

Comment: Please update your question with the error and details that you are seeing. We can help you better with as much details as possible.

Comment: This is the error Error 2 'ProjectMobile.SingleWork.GetItemList()': not all code paths return a value

Comment: Either change this `private string GetItemList()` to `private void GetItemList()` or make `GetItemList()` return a string

Comment: Did this answer your question? If yes please let me know I'll put it up as an answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably get rid of the second/private `GetItemList` method. Also don't name two different methods the same when posting as that makes it confusing. I would refactor your second method to something like:

```cs
var items = GetItemList().ToList();
foreach (var item in items)
{
     lField.Items.Add(item.SomeStringPropertyOnSingleSignerTable);
};
```

or

```
var items = GetItemList().Select(x => x.SomeStringPropertyOnSingleSignerTable)
                         .Distinct()
                         .ToList();
foreach (string option in items)
{
    lField.Items.Add(option);
};
```

As far as the error goes, it is because your method `private string GetItemList()` doesn't return a string but you declared that it does. I wouldn't name a method `GetItemList` if it returned only a string, it *should* probably return `IEnumerable<T>` or some kind of collection.